# How to map 2d point from one coordinate system to another

Tags: opengl, 2d, coordinates, points

I have some source points which are between (0,100) imagine a coordinate system top left of that is (0,0) and bottom right is (100,100).
And destination coordinate system is a space between (-1/2, 1/2).
some points are like this :

```
 x=0,y=0  --->  x'=-1/2,y'=1/2
 x=50,y=50  --->  x'=0,y'=0
 x=100,y=100  --->  x'=1/2,y'=-1/2
```

Now how can I map any point from first coordinate to the second?
any help really appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming a linear transformation is what you are looking for.

So `x->ax+b, y->cy+d`

Generally, start with the `(0,0)`, as that's easier
`0->b` and `0->d`, so `b=-1/2, d=1/2`

And now trivially comes the rest `50->50a-1/2=0` so `a=1/100`, and `50c+1/2=0` so `c=-1/100`

Overall, use `x->x/100-1/2` and `y->-y/100+1/2`

Comment: thanks for your reply! now using this transformation imagine y=5-->y'=5/100-1/2=-0.45 ,but it shouldn't be negative.am I wrong?

Comment: oops, I missed the minus/no minus sign. Corrected the answer
y=5->0.45, but x=5->-0.45